# C# SSL connection actively refused

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

I'm creating an application that requires an encrypted connection, and am having problems. I am running both the client and server from the same computer. If I connect without SSL (via TCPClient and TCPListener, everything works perfectly fine. However, using the [SSLStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) keeps giving me SocketException 0x80004005 "Connection Actively Refused". I've been looking around at other posts and I can't seem to pinpoint my problem.

Client:

```
private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string serverCertName = COMPUTER_NAME;
        string machineName = "127.0.0.1";

        SslStream stream = runClient(machineName, serverCertName, int.Parse(clientPort.Text));

        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We can write to the stream. We have a connection!");
        }
        splitFile(this.sourceName);
    }

    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
        object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //disallow communication with unauthenticated servers
        return false;
    }

    public static SslStream runClient(string machineName, string serverName, int port)
    {
        //create client socket, machineName is the host running the server
        //THIS IS WHERE EVERYTHING FAILS
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, port);
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(),
            false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

        //server should match that is on that server cert
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {

            }
            client.Close();
            return null;
        }

        //encode message as byte array for testing, etc
        return sslStream;
    }
```

Server:

```
static X509Certificate serverCertificate = null;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        int port = 13000;
        string certificate = COMPUTER_NAME;

        runServer(ip, port, certificate);
    }

    /// Start the ssl tcp listener
    public static void runServer(IPAddress ip, int port, string certificate)
    {
        serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            processClient(client);
        }
    }

    //executes if a client has connected. Create the SslStream using the connected client's stream
    static void processClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);

        //authenticate the server, but doesn't require the client to authenticate
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
            //set timeouts to 5 seconds. Seems like a long time. If nothing happens after 5 sec it won't happen
            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
            string data = readMessage(sslStream);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm brand new to TCP/IP connections in general in C#, so it's entirely possible I did something silly, wrong, or overly complicated. I had found (via stack overflow) that SslStream was the way to go, but I just can't seem to make it work. Does anybody have any ideas? I'd really appreciate the help.

Thank you much in advance!

Comment: May i know what is the command line you call the client? Let's assume that i call server with C:\>MyServer C:\myServer.cer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to authenticate as a client, but your server is not authenticating as a server. Try and make sure that this is happening at the same time and it should work.

Comment: Can you please explain more details? i getting the same error as well